# Polymorphism with struct from outside my package

Tags: go, polymorphism

I'm trying to build a method that, using the Kubernetes client-go library, fetches and returns the actual Resources for a given `*metav1.OwnerReference`. I have this:

```golang
func fetchResource(ref *metav1.OwnerReference, options *RequestOptions) (*metav1.ObjectMeta, error) {
    switch ref.Kind {
    case "ReplicaSet":
        return options.Clientset.AppsV1().ReplicaSets(options.Namespace).Get(options.Context, ref.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
    case "Deployment":
        return options.Clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(options.Namespace).Get(options.Context, ref.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
    case "Job":
        fallthrough
    // more stuff...
    default:
        return nil, nil
    }
}
```

This code does not compile because:

> cannot use options.Clientset.AppsV1().ReplicaSets(options.Namespace).Get(options.Context, ref.Name, (metav1.GetOptions literal)) (value of type *"k8s.io/api/apps/v1".ReplicaSet) as *"k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".ObjectMeta value in return statement

My guess was that since the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/api/apps/v1#Deployment) says that basically all resources embedd the `metav1.ObjectMeta`, I could use it as a return type.

I tried creating and returning an `interface` instead, but realized I can't implement it for types outside my package:

```golang
type K8sResource interface {
    Name() string
    Kind() string
    OwnerReferences() []metav1.OwnerReference
}

func (pod *corev1.Pod) Name() string {
    return pod.Name
}
func (pod *corev1.Pod) Kind() string {
    return pod.Kind
}
func (pod *corev1.Pod) OwnerReferences() []metav1.OwnerReference {
    return pod.OwnerReferences
}
```

This code does not compile because:

> invalid receiver *"k8s.io/api/core/v1".Pod (type not defined in this package)

What would be the idiomatic and correct solution here?

Comment: If the individual types all embed the ObjectMeta, and it is the ObjectMeta that you want to return, then you can do that by simply referencing the embedded field. `result, err := ...Get(...)`; `return result.ObjectMeta, err`.

Comment: *"but realized I can't implement it for types outside my package"* -- Correct, but you can implement the interface on thin wrapper types that hold an instance of the imported concrete types.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/__F2dnbljTK

Comment: @mkopriva in response to your second comment: What would that look like? Wouldn't the same problem occur when I try to store the actual type in the thin wrapper struct? Can you give an example?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/yA__8lmGGXk

Comment: @mkopriva nice, thank you. Seems like a lot of work for something so simple. The reason your structs start with lower-case letters is because they aren't meant to be exported, correct?
If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, lower-casing the first letter causes the identifier to not be accessible outside of the package in which it is declared. You can of course write the wrappers in your app with upper-case first letter if you would like to use them in other packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the imported types as an interface that they don't already implement, you can wrap them in types that do implement it.

For example:

```golang
type K8sResource interface {
    Name() string
    Kind() string
    OwnerReferences() []metav1.OwnerReference
}
```

```golang
type replicaSet struct{ *v1.ReplicaSet }

func (s replicaSet) Name() string {
    return s.ReplicaSet.Name
}
func (s replicaSet) Kind() string {
    return s.ReplicaSet.Kind
}
func (s replicaSet) OwnerReferences() []metav1.OwnerReference {
    return s.ReplicaSet.OwnerReferences
}
```

```golang
func fetchResource(ref *metav1.OwnerReference, options *RequestOptions) (K8sResource, error) {
    switch ref.Kind {
    case "ReplicaSet":
        res, err := options.Clientset.AppsV1().ReplicaSets(options.Namespace).Get(options.Context, ref.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return replicaSet{res}, nil // wrap it up
    case "Pod":
        res, err := options.Clientset.AppsV1().Pods(options.Namespace).Get(options.Context, ref.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return pod{res}, nil // wrap it up
    case "Job":
        fallthrough
    // more stuff...
    default:
        return nil, nil
    }
}
```

Comment: When I implement `Name()` by returning `s.Name`, my compiler tells me `k8s/resources.go:31:10: cannot use s.Name (type func() string) as type string in return argument`. If I change the functions name to not be the same as the struct field I'm accessing, it works. Can I give the compiler a hint?

Comment: @LukasKnuth You can access the conflicting field by directly going through the embedded field. Note that an embedded field is automatically assigned the name of its type ([example](https://play.golang.org/p/WurhhDmUUZO)). So, in this case: `s.ReplicaSet.Name`.